# Setting Memcached constants in PHP

Tags: php, memcached, constants

I'm using Memcached PHP library (based on libmemcached) and I'm wondering how can I change  [predefined constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.constants.php) in PHP. I'd like to use key distribution based on ketama.

Memcached is compiled as a PHP extension.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use setOption:

```
$this->_Memcache =& new Memcached();
$this->_Memcache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_SERIALIZER, Memcached::SERIALIZER_PHP);
$this->_Memcache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_NO_BLOCK, true);
$this->_Memcache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_TCP_NODELAY, true);
$this->_Memcache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_BUFFER_WRITES, true);
$this->_Memcache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_SERVER_FAILURE_LIMIT,3);
$this->_Memcache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_HASH,Memcached::HASH_CRC);
```

etc... etc...